# Should pressure vessel head be thicker than wall

Tags: structural-engineering, pressure, gas, pressure-vessel, compressed-gases

I wondering should the head of a rectangular pressure vessel cylinder be thicker than the wall ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a rectangular cylinder?

Comment: The answer to this likely depends on the pressure and the dimensions. You may want to add these pieces of information to the question. Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

So if the vessel is rectangular , I assume a flat heads, essentially no different than a side. So the size of sides and heads would determine the necessary thickness. In traditional cylindrical pressure vessels the stress is reduced by about half in domed heads , so they may be thinner .